# Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF' linebreak-style

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, line-endings

When using eslint in the gulp project i have encountered a problem with error like this
`Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'  linebreak-style` and I am using Windows environment for the running gulp and the entire error log is given below

```
 Kiran (master *) Lesson 4 $ gulp
 Using gulpfile c:\Users\Sai\Desktop\web-build-tools\4\
 gulpfile.js
 Starting 'styles'...
 Finished 'styles' after 17 ms
 Starting 'lint'...
 'lint' errored after 1.14 s
 ESLintError in plugin 'gulp-eslint'
 sage: Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'.
 ails: fileName: c:\Users\Sai\Desktop\web-build-tools\4\js\extra.js



$>Users\Sai\Desktop\web-build-tools\4\js\extra.js
error  Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'  linebreak-style
```

I have also including **extra.js** file as the error indicating possible mistake.

```
function getWindowHeight() {
    return window.innerHeight;
}

getWindowHeight();
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Check if you have the `linebreak-style` rule configure as below either in your .eslintrc or in source code:

```
/*eslint linebreak-style: ["error", "unix"]*/
```

Since you're working on Windows, you may want to use this rule instead:

```
/*eslint linebreak-style: ["error", "windows"]*/
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/linebreak-style) of `linebreak-style`:

> When developing with a lot of people all having different editors, VCS
> applications and operating systems it may occur that different line
> endings are written by either of the mentioned (might especially
> happen when using the windows and mac versions of SourceTree
> together).
>
> The linebreaks (new lines) used in windows operating system are
> usually carriage returns (CR) followed by a line feed (LF) making it a
> carriage return line feed (CRLF) whereas Linux and Unix use a simple
> line feed (LF). The corresponding control sequences are `"\n"` (for LF)
> and `"\r\n"` for (CRLF).

This is a rule that is automatically fixable. The `--fix` option on the command line automatically fixes problems reported by this rule.

But if you wish to retain `CRLF` line-endings in your code (as you're working on Windows) do not use the `fix` option.

Comment: This is more of a hack. The other answer by @The Coder is correct. You need to change the config of the project

Comment: I am not sure if this solution works for multi platform developers where some developers work in Unix and some on Windows. I think this should be best handled by the version control not the IDE or Lint is a moot point. Answer by @vnxyz worked and should be accepted IMO.

Comment: This response is totally wrong. If the team agreed to have a linting rule with line-ending LF and you have a windows machine, then you must implement a set of steps so that everything works on your machine without touching the linting rule.

Answer (score 286):

I found it useful (where I wanted to ignore line feeds and not change any files) to ignore them in the .eslintrc using linebreak-style as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008668/1129108

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'google',
  quotes: [2, 'single'],
  globals: {
    SwaggerEditor: false
  },
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  rules:{
    "linebreak-style": 0
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually the second highest (and not selected) answer, in my case I was working in a repository where the primary people working on it were on Macs and I was code reviewing on a PC, didn't really want to change anything for that reason.

Answer (score 168):

If you are using vscode and you are on **Windows** i would recommend you to **click the option at the bottom-right of the window and set it to LF from CRLF**. Because we should not turn off the configuration just for sake of removing errors on **Windows**

If you don't see LF / CLRF, then right click the status bar and select Editor End of Line.

[image: menu]

Comment: How to set this configuration to global in one project? i have to do this for every file

Comment: The global setting in VSCode seems to be: `Settings -> Text Editor -> Files -> Eol`, set to `\n`. This appears to only apply to new files though, you'll still have to switch each existing file over manually.

Answer (score 54):

Here is a really good way to manage this error. You can put the below line in .eslintrc.js file.

Based on the operating system, it will take appropriate line endings.

```
rules: {
        'linebreak-style': ['error', process.platform === 'win32' ? 'windows' : 'unix'],
 }
```

Comment: This is a clever way to manage this error with team members on both Mac and Windows machines.  Is there a downside that I don't see?

Comment: @Scott Thanks! I do not see any downside.

Comment: trying to understand why this could be less error prone of  : `'linebreak-style': ['error', 'windows'], `

Comment: @CarmineTambascia when team members work on the same repo with different machine OS(windows, Linux and Mac) then it will take appropriate line ending -https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style#options

Comment: I undertood that but anyway this won't work with any CPU of 64 byte, and I don't see what add to the exception of add only "windows" and include all of them

Comment: @CarmineTambascia For any windows system, process.platform will always return win32. so, There is no issues.

Comment: Thank you. This answer worked perfectly for me. I'm in the situation where we have many devs working in Mac and Windows, and we use a .gitattributes file to have the line endings automatically converted for the native OS.

Answer (score 33):

If you want it in **crlf** (Windows Eol), go to File -> Preferences -> Settings. Type "end of line" in the User tab and make sure **Files: Eol** is set to **\r\n** and if you're using the Prettier extension, make sure **Prettier: End of Line** is set to **crlf**. [image] Finally, on your eslintrc file, add this rule: `'linebreak-style': ['error', 'windows']` [image]

Comment: Voted up for the useful photos, 10x

Comment: "go to File -> Preferences -> Settings" What app should this be done in?

Comment: Prettier setting was my issue. Thanks CLUTCHER

Comment: Please note, what is an editor is in a first screenshot.

Answer (score 24):

add to our rule in the .eslintrc file 'linebreak-style':0 in Vue js

```
  rules: {
    'linebreak-style':0,
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

git config core.autocrlf false

git rm --cached -r .

git reset --hard

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to how these git commands address the problem described in the question?

Comment: This is the one that worked for me but I have no idea what's happening

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm pretty sure when you git clone it messes up with auto converting the linebreaks, and basically this turns it off

Answer (score 17):

Just made `autocrlf` param in .gitconfig file `false` and recloned the code. It worked!

`[core]
    autocrlf = false`

Comment: Your fix worked for me, editing eslintrc to add linebreak-style did not work.

Comment: That may cause more issues than it solves since the autocrlf is very helpful when mixing Windows and Unix as Windows tools will add crlf and unix tools lf.

Comment: For those looking for the file. On unix: `nano ~/.gitconfig`

Comment: @janisch This will change the setting on the user-level, meaning it will be applied to all projects! Most likely you'd only want to change it for a specific project, in which case you'd edit `.git/config` in the repo directory instead.

Comment: `autocrlf = false` didn't work for me, by the way. I manually converted all line breaks to LF, but Git would immediately convert them back to CRLF in every modified file as soon as I tried to commit. The correct setting for me to be able to keep LF was `autocrlf = input` (and no re-checkout is necessary).

Answer (score 15):

The same situation occurred when I was using VSCode with eslint. If you use VSCode,

1 - Click area that name can be both LF or CRLF where at the bottom right of the VScode.

2 - Select LF from the drop-down menu.

That's worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Happen with me because I ran `git config core.autocrlf true` and I forgot to rever back.

After that, when I checkout/pull new code, all LF (break line in Unix) was replaced by CRLF  (Break line in Windows).

I ran linter, and all error messages are `Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'`

To fix the issue, I checked  `autocrlf` value by running `git config --list | grep autocrlf` and I got:

```
core.autocrlf=true
core.autocrlf=false
```

I edited the global GIT config `~/.gitconfig` and replaced `autocrlf = true` by `autocrlf = false`.

After that, I went to my project and do the following (assuming the code in `src/` folder):

```
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2);
rm -rf src/*
git checkout $CURRENT_BRANCH src/
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using vscode I would recommend you to click the option at the bottom-right of the window and set it to LF from CRLF..this fixed my errors

Comment: where exactly is this?

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to change to `LF` and you are using VS Code you can do it per file like so:

[image: Graphic showing how to change from CRLF to LF using VS CODE]

Answer (score 4):

I set linebreak-style to 0, but not working.

```
rules: {
    "linebreak-style": 0,
 },
```

so then I found out need to change every files from "CRLF" to "LF", and that take lots time.

When cloning a project, Git automatically converts LF to CRLF which causes the error.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

To avoid this automatic conversion, run “git config --global core.autocrlf false” in Git Bash before cloning the project.

Comment: When cloning a project, Git automatically converts LF to CRLF which causes the error. Run "git config core.autocrlf false" in Git Bash before cloning the project will help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **WebStorm** and you are on **Windows** i would recommend you to click settings/editor/code style/general tab and select "windows(\r\n) from the dropdown menu.These steps will also apply for Rider.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case (vue.js project, created using vue-cli) the lint problem `Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF' linebreak-style` was related to Prettier.
From version >= 2 Prettier replace all line endings with "lf": https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#end-of-line

Since I'm using Windows to develop I set these 3 (git, eslint, prettier) configuration to avoid line endings problems:

1. **Git**: I set `git config --global core.autocrlf true`
2. **eslint**: in .eslintrc.js file I configured:

```
      module.exports = {
      rules: {
        'linebreak-style': ['error', 'windows'],
      },
    };
```

3. **prettier**: And finally in `prettier.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    endOfLine: "crlf",
};
```

Comment: I believe the issue has to do more about use codebase that is been "saved" with LF rules and then indeed work on Windows that use 'CRLF'. The question is, are the above setting guarantee that once the code is pushed, is back to LF formatting?

Comment: What I meant with my previous comment is that as from another answer, in VSC is possible to toggle between LF and crlf but then that is seen as a change by git, but in reality there isn't been any or any in term of a real commit.

Comment: I have read further https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style and this eslint exception rule is the most simple and working to avoid this error pop up in vsc in windows. Alternative is provide the .gitattributes file

Answer (score 2):

The `"endOfLine": "auto"` setting in `.eslintrc.js` and `.prettierrc` files worked for me.

File `.eslintrc.js` should have:

```
rules: {
    /*  ...the other code is omitted for the brevity */
    'arrow-body-style': [1, 'as-needed'],
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': [
        'error',
        {
            semi: false,
            singleQuote: true,
            useTabs: true,
            endOfLine: 'auto', /* this setting should be included */
        },
    ],
```

File `.prettierrc` should have:

```
{
    "semi": false,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "endOfLine": "auto" /* this setting should be included */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tips: **Make sure you have installed Git** as the picture if not do that first.
You can take other features as default, You can **choose visual studio code as the default editor**. helps you a lot later.

[image]

**Windows Users:**
Uninstall Visual Studio Code then reinstalled it again and EditorConfig should work just fine.

NOTE => Uninstalling Visual Studio Code still leaves the old settings and extensions! remove Visual Studio Code on Windows completely

### Uninstalled Visual Studio

1. This PC > Local disck (C) Users > CurrentUser > AppData > Local > Programs > Microsoft VS Code

   1. Unins000.exe or Uninstall it from conrol panel
2. This PC > Local disck (C) Users > CurrentUser > AppData > Local > Roaming

   1. **Code** => Folder should be delete it
3. This PC > Local disck (C) Users > CurrentUser >

   1. **.vscode** => Folder should be delete it
4. reinstall vs code it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add the easier way. On the bottom right of VScode click the LF or CRLF to toggle between them. [See Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJj52.png)

Answer (score 1):

for me, I fixed the issue by setting "endOfLine": "lf" in the.prettierrc file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above really worked for me.
All of them are temporary solutions that are going to work for you but not for the team, like changing the linting rule or totally disabling it.
If the team agreed to have a linting rule with line-ending LF and you have a windows machine, then you must implement a set of steps so that everything works on your machine without touching the linting rule.

First of all, check your global settings:

```
git config --global --list
```

You want to make sure that you have the value

```
core.autocrlf=false
```

If that's not the case, then run:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

This command disables automatic line ending conversion, ensuring that Git will not automatically change line endings when you commit or check out files.

In the terminal, move to your solution folder, example:

```
C:\git\my_project>
```

and run the following command:

```
git config core.eol lf
```

This will set the line ending type to use in the working directory for files that are marked as text

In your solution folder you should find a file named .gitattributes, open it and make sure you have the following instruction into it:

```
* text eol=lf
```

If not there, create it.

This will tell Git to always convert line endings to LF on checkout. You should use this for files that must keep LF endings, even on Windows.

Finally you need to refresh your repository (Stash or discard you local changes).
To update all files on the current branch to reflect the new configuration, run the following commands:

```
git rm -rf --cached .
git reset --hard HEAD
```

To display the rewritten, normalized files, run the following command.

```
git status
```

Optionally, to commit any outstanding changes in your repository, run the following command.

```
git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
```

Additionally, if you are using VS Code, you can enforce the LF line ending:

*File -> Preferences -> Settings*

[image]

References:

- https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 0):

Try using the linter's --fix flag to resolve the issue.

> eslint filePath --fix

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `LF rule` was set in a file read by the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` in `pom.xml`.
The `${skipCheckstyle}` environment variable was not set.
This way I skipped the whole check.

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <skip>${skipCheckstyle}</skip>
    <configLocation>${top.dir}/src/main/config/checkstyle/checker.xml</configLocation>
```

Answer (score -1):

run: $ `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

delete repo and clone again