# How can I write a ESLint rule for "linebreak-style", changing depending on Windows or Unix?

Tags: javascript, windows, unix, eslint, line-endings

As we all know, the linebreaks (new line) used in Windows are usually carriage returns (CR) followed by a line feed (LF) i.e. (CRLF) whereas, Linux and Unix use a simple line feed (LF)

Now, in my case, my build server uses supports Linux and Unix format so, below rule is working perfectly on build server:

```
linebreak-style: ["error", "unix"]
```

But I am doing development on Windows and I need to update rule on each *git pull/git push* as below,

```
linebreak-style: ["error", "windows"]
```

So, is there any way to write a generic *linebreak-style* rule to support both environments, Linux/Unix and Windows?

**Note**: I am using ECMAScript6[js], WebStorm[ide] for development

Any solutions/suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `LF` all the time (for JS files)? Browsers as well as IDE supports them just fine.

Comment: ESLint tests will fails for LF if, environment is windows.

Comment: I see -- thanks for clarifying this (not a JS person myself)

Comment: What happen if I added both ["error", "unix", "windows"], It helps to resolve the warning in my text editor, but I am not sure about the build ability on the server

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The eslint configuration file can be **a regular `.js` file** (ie, not JSON, but full JS with logic) that exports the configuration object.

That means you could change the configuration of the `linebreak-style` rule depending on your current environment (or any other JS logic you can think of).

For example, to use a different `linebreak-style` configuration when your node environment is 'prod':

```
module.exports = {
    "root": true,
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "rules": {
        // windows linebreaks when not in production environment
        "linebreak-style": ["error", process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod' ? "unix" : "windows"]
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
$ NODE_ENV=prod node_modules/.bin/eslint src/test.js

src/test.js
  1:25  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  2:30  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  3:36  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  4:26  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  5:17  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  6:50  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  7:62  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style
  8:21  error  Expected linebreaks to be 'CRLF' but found 'LF'  linebreak-style

✖ 8 problems (8 errors, 0 warnings)

$ NODE_ENV=dev node_modules/.bin/eslint src/test.js
$ # no errors
```

Comment: Building on this answer I switched to detecting the normal line ending for the platform instead of having to specify the environment, so: `"linebreak-style": ["error", (require("os").EOL === "\r\n" ? "windows" : "unix")]`

Comment: Uh, you can't set the variables that way on the dev environment if the dev environment is Windows, so the example of setting NODE_ENV=dev that way is invalid. Can you correct it?

Answer (score 82):

I spent time trying to find how to shut off the linkbreak-style and lost it due to reverting some of my code I thought others my like to have this as well.

In the `.eslintrc` file you can also set `linebreak-style` to `0` which shuts off the [linebreak](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/linebreak-style) feature:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'google',
  quotes: [2, 'single'],
  globals: {
    SwaggerEditor: false
  },
  env: {
    browser: true
  },
  rules:{
    "linebreak-style": 0   // <----------
  }
};
```

Comment: Something you should never do, especially when you're not the only developer around ;)

Comment: Not a solution, just hiding the pain.

Comment: i had to type the "linebreak-style", is there any extension or something for intllegience for all the available options?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but doesn't git typically convert line endings in any case? Would that fail to catch/resolve issues that eslint would? (Assuming the team is using git).

Answer (score 20):

In your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
"rules": {
  "linebreak-style": ["error", (process.platform === "win32" ? "windows" : "unix")], // https://stackoverflow.com/q/39114446/2771889
}
```

See also: [How do I determine the current operating system with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js)

Comment: Does not work for me on Windows. Error: 'value expected'

Answer (score 11):

## A better option

### .editorconfig `end_of_line`

Add the [end_of_line](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#end_of_line) rule in [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/#example-file) file:

```
[*]
end_of_line= lf
```

[EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/#example-file) is an extension for most code editors nowadays that **changes the contents of the file you just saved**. This rule enforces that all line endings are always **unix consistent** (`\n`) each time a developer saves a file (note: [**MacOs no longer** uses `\r` => `cr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552782/6225838)).
For enforcing **windows** line endings (`\r\n`) use `crlf`.

This option is preferable since it avoids all line ending changes to be recorded in the project's repository (version control).

## Not so optimal options...

As an [EditorConfig note](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#end_of_line) mentions:

> if you want to use native line endings between different OSes, it is better not to set this option and leave that task to the VCS! In the future **we might add a value like native** for this scenario (cf [#226](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/226)).

This would be a replacement for the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122799/6225838)'s solution:

```
"linebreak-style": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod' ? "unix" : "windows"
```

Which is still better than completely disabling the rule (`"linebreak-style": 0`): developers/contributors inconsistently may use their preferred line endings in the same file...

Comment: the solution with .editorconfig still works in 2023. 

Answer (score 6):

.eslintc for Windows visualstudio code

```html
{
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "rules":{
    "linebreak-style": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, it just turns the valuable feature off. Now you're going to end up with a code base in disarray.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Vs Code on Windows, go to your ".eslintrc.json" file (or '.js' depending on which option you chose when setting up your ESLint); this file will usually be found in the root folder of your project; and under rules add the linebreak option to use Windows CRLF as follows:

```
"rules": {
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"]
}
```

Save the file and when you go back to your JavaScript file, all those pesky red lines will disappear.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few answers playing around with`.eslintrc` and one even suggest switching off the rule altogether.

However, what I prefer is to change VCS settings to checkout `LF` instead of `CRLF`. Assuming even in windows env, modern IDE should handle `LF` just fine. The drawback is some windows software like notepad aren't going to like it. But this way you will be warned if you have incorrect linebreak style. And it is less likely for people to commit incorrect linebreak style even if their VCS is misconfigured. Simply run `git config --global core.autocrlf false` or follow instructions on [How do I force git to use LF instead of CR+LF under windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517190/how-do-i-force-git-to-use-lf-instead-of-crlf-under-windows)

Anyway, turning off the rule is discouraged in general as this will impact other team members, unless you have all of team's consent.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, **VS code** had default settings of line break **CRLF**, because
it was freshly installed. I had to go to change that by: `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the command palette and search for:

> Change End of Line Sequence

There you can switch it to **LF**.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the config file required to alter ESLint rules for linebreak-style may change depending on whether you want to alter local, project or global settings, it searches for local first which overrides those further up the tree, so alter at the top of the tree to propagate down for global

I used airbnb style and my global settings were located here: node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/style.js:

If you are unsure on the location of the file you can always search for a list of files that contain text relating to the settings, on Linux to find all files with linebreak settings navigate to the folder where ESLint was installed and use:

```
grep -r linebreak
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to set it up for all linux/unix, mac and windows, just replace the
`linebreak-style` in eslintrc.json to
`"linebreak-style": ["error","unix | windows"]`