# ESLint keeps returning Definition for rule 'eslint linebreak-style' was not found in vueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

No matter how much I tried, vueJS keeps returning

```
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/eslint%20linebreak-style  Definition for rule 'eslint linebreak-style' was not found
  src\components\Register.vue:1:1
  <template>
   ^
```

This are the steps have taken so far.
in

> src\components\Register.vue:1:1

I included this

> /* eslint-disable */

at the top of the script, but that still dosent stop it from failing.
Also in VS Code, I changed it from

> CRLF

to

> LF

, then run `npm run lint -- --fix` but still dosen't fix the problem.
I also edited

> .eslintrc.js

by adding all of these at different stage `"linebreak-style": 0,`
and this too  `//["error", (process.platform === "win32" ? "windows" : "unix")], // https://stackoverflow.com/q/39114446/2771889`
and this also `"eslint linebreak-style": ["error", "windows"],` but all to know avail.

I also added the above codes to

> node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb-base\rules\style.js

and still, ESLint refuses to go away.

NB: Am using Windows 8.1

What else can I do to solve the problem.